# Not able to connect node.js app to SQL DB using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a post using node.js app in the SQL DB using ORM Sequelize

[post.js and whole file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM7nk.png)

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// const mysql = require("mysql2");
const db = require("./models");
db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
   app.listen(5001, () => {
   console.log("Server running on port 3001");
 });
  })
 .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

**config.js**

```
{
"development": {
"username": "password",
"password": "password",
"database": "Message_db",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql",
"port":1433

},
 "test": {
"username": "root",
"password": null,
"database": "database_test",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql"
   },
 "production": {
    "username": "root",
     "password": null,
     "database": "database_production",
       "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql"
 }
}
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEAIU.png)

[my port in ssms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBEEb.png)

I don't understand what is the issue since I have followed all the steps from the video.

Comment: I don't know Sequelize, but you're listening on port 5001 and in the config.js you're starting sequelize(?) on port 1433.

Comment: Also your log `5001, console.log("Server running on port 3001"` makes no sense, but that's just aestethics.

Comment: plz ignore the comments in console log actually was trying many ports so ight have missed to change it

Comment: You haven't shown all your code here. We need to see what's in models.js. It seems like a lot of code / setup is missing. Not sure why you've commented out mysql2 here. Also, what video? We don't have any context.

Comment: @Fusseldieb actually it doesnt mtter what port u listen on node app vs the port you want to connect on sql because sql will be running on a different port so in config i am just saying connect to that port

Comment: You indicated a dialect as `mysql` meanwhile you shown in the `ssms` that it's MS SQL Server

Comment: @Anatoly let me check on that

Comment: @kevintechie no video in specific just some random video plz ignore that as well

Comment: Good eye, @Anatoly, haven't seen that. Abhishek, MSSQL (ssms) and MySQL are ***NOT*** the same. They won't work together. They sound like the same language, but they are NOT.

Comment: thanks a lot guys dialect was the issue

Comment: I really am honored to be a part of this community I have been struggling for 3 days on this created 3 projects for this and saw so many videos thanks a lot guys....... respect ++

Answer (score 0):

You indicated a dialect as `mysql` meanwhile you shown in the ssms that it's MS SQL Server. It's two different SQL servers. Please indicate a proper dialect.